# Having trouble with sequence action

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, fade, skaction

I want my menu to fade into view after waiting for a few seconds. I tried putting the action sequence in both the initWithSize method and the sprites themselves but it doesn't work at all. Can someone please check my code and tell me what's wrong with it?

```
-(void) addTitleBreaker:(CGSize)size {
    SKSpriteNode *titleBreaker = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"titleBreaker"];
    //resize title breaker
    titleBreaker.size = CGSizeMake(titleBreaker.size.width/2, titleBreaker.size.height/2);
    //position title breaker
    CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(180, 364);
    titleBreaker.position = myPoint;
    //add action
    /*SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
    SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:5];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,fadeIn]];

    [titleBreaker runAction:sequence];*/
    [self addChild:titleBreaker];   
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:(29.0f/255) green:(29.0f/255) blue:(29.0f/255) alpha:1.0];

        //create fade in action
        /*SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
        SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:5];
        SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,fadeIn]];


        [self runAction:sequence];*/
        [self addTitleBrick:size];
        [self addTitleBreaker:size];
        [self addPlayButton:size];
        [self addLeaderboards:size];
        [self AddHighScoreLabel:size];
        [self addInfoLogo:size];
        [self addSoundLogo:size];
        [self addMusicLogo:size];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: please note that I'm aware that the code for the actions are just comments and that I tried it without them being so. I put the comments so they don't effect my code when I'm doing the other things.

Comment: try it with a fade out action, and try without the sequence. perhaps the node needs to start already faded out for the fade in to work?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments this won't work because there's nothing to "fade in".

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/fadeInWithDuration:)

> When the action executes, the node’s alpha property animates ***from its current value*** to 1.0.

Note the section I've emphasised, when you create the `SKSpriteNode` it's alpha will be `1.0` so you need to firstly set that to 0 after instantiating it:

```
titleBreaker.alpha = 0;
```

Then your `[SKAction fadeInWithDuration:5]` will work.